# How to get Bootstrap Alert text when user login

Tags: protractor, karma-jasmine, end-to-end

I am new in protractor and now My Question is how to get Bootstrap Alert message text when Login. Alert Message element Define only one time in index.html

```
    var email = element(by.model('login_vm.loginData.lmail'));
    var password = element(by.model('login_vm.loginData.lpass'));
    var loginButton = element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-submit'));
    var error = element(by.css('.hehehsandeep'));

    it('should redirect to login page', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8000/login');
        loginURL = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    });

    it('should expect valid email and password', function() {
        email.sendKeys('sandeepsingh@innotical.com');
        password.sendKeys('sandeep');
        loginButton.click();
        expect(error.getText()).toMatch('Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)');
    });
```

login successfully work but when match with error message showing result in command prompt:

```
Failures:
1) Authentication Capabilties should expect valid email and password
  Message:
    Expected 'Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)' to match 'Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)'.
```

please help me out....

Comment: What if you try `toEqual` or `toBe`, does it still throw the error?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you put:

```
expect('Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)').toMatch('Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)');
```

you'd still get:

> Expected 'Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)' to match 'Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)'.

The problem is that `toMatch()` takes the argument and interprets it as a regular expression. There are characters that have special meaning in regular expressions, like `!`, `(` and `)` in your case. In order for these characters to be used as literals, you need to escape them:

```
expect('Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)').toMatch('Welcome\! sandeep \(sandeepsingh@innotical.com\)');
```

Though, much easier would be to use `toEqual()` instead:

```
expect('Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)').toEqual('Welcome! sandeep (sandeepsingh@innotical.com)');
```

Comment: @Gunderson thanks! And I am learning from yours, hope to see you more on SO.